# FineTuned VGG16 achieving great results on epoch 1, is this normal?

Tags: classification, deep-learning, overfitting, transfer-learning

I'm training a model to classify whether a person is smiling (showing teeth) or not.

I'm using Keras and I trained a VGG16 model loaded with the ImageNet weights, froze the first 4 layers and added a dropout + a dense layer at the end.

I am using image augmentation and I've done [hyperparameter optimization](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas).

I have around 3000 images for each class (smiling / not_smiling) and I'm finding it so strange that it's taking the model just 1 or 2 epochs to achieve about 0.98 accuracy with minimum loss on both train and validation sets. Is this normal or am I missing something here?

The test set also scored really well which leads me to believe generalization isn't an issue either, making the results convincing. The confusion matrixes for each set also look good.

I'd like to understand how am I getting such good results after 1 or 2 epochs, could it be the fact that the dataset is easy to classify or am I being fooled?

Comment: This question would be a lot more answerable if you report the accuracy *without any finetuning*, i.e calculate FC output of the original imagenet VGG model on your images (freezing all weights), and then use those to with a single-layer dense classifier that your train. You could also just run a random forest on the FC outputs. You'll likely get quite good results right-off-the-bat. I remember you can get really decent race and gender prediction on faces without finetuning, for example. So, it's likely not surprising.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AlexR. , I will try what you've suggested. I was very skeptical about my results.

Comment: @Alex R. I've tested your suggestion, froze all weights and trained the FC layer. I got results just as good as the method I've described in my post, and again, using 1 epoch only. Does this mean anything?

Comment: It means that if you want better results, you either need more data, or need more epochs when finetuning the entire model. Keep in mind that smiles can be rather ambiguous (even if they are human-labelled), so that's something to consider as well.

Comment: The thing is, I'm getting nearly perfect results on both _fine-tuning_ and _frozen model + FC layer_. Isn't t it rather strange?

Comment: It's impossible to answer that without reproducible code and training data. Have you checked whether maybe your smile images differ from nonsmile images in some obvious way, such as image size, etc.?

Comment: The main difference would have to be the teeth pixels. All the images have a single person with the same pose, like an ID or passport pose, but some are smiling some are not.